# Faster function iteration on Pandas df with axis=1

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following function that allows me to calculate the marketing spend on my advertising campaigns.

The problem is that it's now taking too long (over 15 minutes) to apply the function to said dataframe, as it now has more than 8 months of historical data.

I have no idea if there's a way to speed up the process. Any help would be appreciated if you know a faster way to iter through rows.

```
def actual_spend_atlas(row):

    filterdatemediaplanid_day = (atlas_df.Date == row.Date) & (atlas_df.MediaPlanIndex == row.MediaPlanIndex)
    filterdatemediaplanid_total = (atlas_df.MediaPlanIndex == row.MediaPlanIndex)

    total_impressions_day = atlas_df.ix[filterdatemediaplanid_day, 'Impressions'].sum()
    total_impressions = atlas_df.ix[filterdatemediaplanid_total, 'Impressions'].sum()


    if row.Amnet == "Amnet":
        spend = atlas_df.AmnetCost * (row.Impressions / filterdatemediaplanid_day)

    if row.CostMethod == 'FLF' or row.CostMethod == 'CPH':

        if total_impressions < 500:
            spend = 0
        else:
            rate = row.BookedRate
            spend = rate * (row.Impressions/ total_impressions)

    elif row.CostMethod == 'CPC':
        spend = row.BookedRate * row.Clicks

    elif row.CostMethod == 'CPM':
        cpm_impressions = row.Impressions / 1000.0
        rate = row.BookedRate
        spend = rate * cpm_impressions

    else:
        spend = 0

    return spend


atlas_df['Spend'] = atlas_df.apply(actual_spend_atlas, axis=1)
```

Comment: Im guessing the speed issues are to do with your first few lines of code where you filter for values which match your rows? If possible, you could try making a dictionary or lookup table for your `filterdatemediaplanid_day` and `filterdatemediaplanid_total` arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get a small speed-up  is swap these two lines:

```
filterdatemediaplanid_day = (atlas_df.Date == row.Date) & (atlas_df.MediaPlanIndex == row.MediaPlanIndex)
filterdatemediaplanid_total = (atlas_df.MediaPlanIndex == row.MediaPlanIndex)
```

to:

```
filterdatemediaplanid_total = (atlas_df.MediaPlanIndex == row.MediaPlanIndex)
filterdatemediaplanid_day = (atlas_df.Date == row.Date) & filterdatemediaplanid_total
```

This part of the code does not serve any purpose:

```
if row.Amnet == "Amnet":
    spend = atlas_df.AmnetCost * (row.Impressions / filterdatemediaplanid_day)
```

Since you don't return right away and afterwards comes an `if/elif/else` block that is guaranteed to modify `spend`, anything you calculate here will be overwritten.

While some people adhere to the single exit policy, I prefer early returns:

```
if row.CostMethod == 'FLF' or row.CostMethod == 'CPH':
    total_impressions = atlas_df.ix[filterdatemediaplanid_total, 'Impressions'].sum()
    if total_impressions >= 500:
        return row.BookedRate * (row.Impressions/ total_impressions)
elif row.CostMethod == 'CPC':
    return row.BookedRate * row.Clicks
elif row.CostMethod == 'CPM':
    return row.BookedRate * row.Impressions / 1000.0
return 0
```

`total_impressions_day` is not used anywhere and `total_impressions` should only be calculated if needed.